# App crashing two linear layout inside other linear layout with java

Tags: java, android

Hey Everyone I want to make a layout in android studio dynamically(not with xml) the structure will be like :
LinearLayout(Horizontal)
--LinearLayout(Vertical)
----TextView1
----TextView2
--LinearLayout(Vertical)
----TextView3
----TextView4

but the app is crashing with error:
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Code:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
LinearLayout linearLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   LinearLayout HLL = new LinearLayout(this);
   LinearLayout V1LL = new LinearLayout(this);
   LinearLayout V2LL = new LinearLayout(this);

   HLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
   V1LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
   V2LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

   V1LL.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fcba03"));
   V2LL.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fc03e3"));

   LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
   );

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            0,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            1
    );


   setContentView(HLL,lp);
   setContentView(V1LL,lp);
   setContentView(V2LL,lp);

   HLL.addView(V1LL);
   HLL.addView(V2LL);


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you setting `setContentView` multiple times? `Activity` can contain just one `View` as content (but this may be `ViewGroup` with multiple childs). just add inner `LinearLayout`s to main parent `LinearLayout` and then call `setContentView` passing only this main one

```
HLL.addView(V1LL);
HLL.addView(V2LL);

setContentView(HLL, lp);
```